# Why i can not change the windows server password?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I want to change the my server password,use the remote desktop and connect to the server and use the CTRL+ALT+DEL to change password,when i click change password that page try to change the password but show me username or password is incorrect,if my username or password incorrect how can i connect that server
what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: So you connecting to the Server as a local account and not a domain account? Also when you press Ctrl Alt Del whilst in RDP are you sure its not performing the Ctrl Alt Del on your local machine instead of the Server?

Answer (score 1):

When you press `ctrl+alt+del` the focus goes back to local PC, so you'll end up changing password of your own PC instead of the remote PC you are connected to.
To change the password on the remote PC do this:

- on the remote desktop, run osk
- Press `ctrl+alt` on your physical keyboard, then use your mouse to click `del` on the on screen keyboard.
- then you click on "change password".

Comment: i use the CTRL+ALT+END